How are they getting a 6,7 % yield in this article?
Ì am reading this article:
https://www.sterling.com.jm/blog/difference-between-yield-and-interest-rate
They write:

A large French Bank has a bond with a 7% coupon and a 2028 call date.
If you pay US 100 for US 100 worth of this bond, you will have both a
7% yield and a 7% interest rate. If you pay US 101 for US 100 worth of
this bond, you will enjoy a 6.7% yield.

I am wondering how they get the 6,7 % yield?
I was thinking something like this:
The article is from december 2022, so the first payment is in 2023? But I get:
$7+7/1,067+7/1,067^2+7/1,067^3+7/1,067^4+107/1,067^5=108,24$.
If I assume the first payment is in 2022 I get:
$7+7/1,067+7/1,067^2+7/1,067^3+7/1,067^4+7/1,067^5+107/1,067^6=108,44$.
Could you please help me?

You cannot compute this without knowing the daycount, business day conventions and dates of the cashflows.

I don't think you should get a coupon payment immediately (no discount).
The yield is not 6,7%, but it is pretty close.


Thank you. I did what you did but started with 2023 instead(and wrote 1 there instead of 2) and got 1,06791, do you think that could be what they meant?

Yes, it is possible. All in all, I wouldn't worry about this question too much.
